# Kernel K-means 実装 in Python

Tags: python, 機械学習, python2

環境: Mac, Jupyter-Notebook, Python2.7
Kernel K-meansを実装したんですが、うまく動作しません。コードにエラーは出ません。どこかの計算が間違っているんだと思いますが、どこかわからないので誰か助けてください。

Algorithmについてはこちらがわかりやすいかと思います
[Link_01](http://lasa.epfl.ch/teaching/lectures/ML_Phd/Slides/kCCA-kKmeans-SpectralClustering.pdf)
[Link_02](https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/kernel-k-means-clustering-algorithm)

とりあえずデータを貼ります、下に実際のコードを書きました。

[image: データ生成]

```
    from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

    class Kernel_Kmeans(object):

        def __init__(self, n_clusters=3, max_iter=50, kernel="linear",
                    gamma=None, degree=3, coef0=1, kernel_params=None):
            self.n_clusters = n_clusters
            self.max_iter = max_iter
            self.kernel = kernel
            self.gamma = gamma
            self.degree = degree
            self.coef0 = coef0
            self.kernel_params = kernel_params

        def kernel_matrix(self, X, Y = None):
            if callable(self.kernel):
                prams = self.kernel_params or {}
            else:
                params = {"gamma": self.gamma,
                          "degree": self.degree,
                          "coef0": self.coef0}

            return pairwise_kernels(X, Y, metric = self.kernel,
                                    filter_params = True, **params)

        def initialize_cluster(self, X):
            self.labels = np.random.choice(xrange(self.n_clusters), X.shape[0])
            #self.cluster_size = np.bincount(self.labels)


        def fit(self, X):
            n_samples = X.shape[0]
            self.initialize_cluster(X)

            for ite in xrange(self.max_iter):
                self.cluster_size = np.bincount(self.labels)
                for i in xrange(n_samples):
                    data = X[self.labels == 0]
                    xm = np.sum(self.kernel_matrix(data, Y = X[i].reshape(1, X.shape[1])))/self.cluster_size[0]
                    mm = np.sum(self.kernel_matrix(data))/(self.cluster_size[0]**2)
                    min_dist = mm - 2*xm 
                    for j in xrange(self.n_clusters

):
                    if j == (self.n_clusters-1):
                        continue
                    tmp_data = X[self.labels == j+1]
                    tmp_xm = np.sum(self.kernel_matrix(data, Y = X[i].reshape(1, X.shape[1])))/self.cluster_size[j+1]
                    tmp_mm = np.sum(self.kernel_matrix(data))/(self.cluster_size[j+1]**2)
                    tmp_dist = tmp_mm - 2*tmp_xm 
                    if tmp_dist < min_dist:
                        min_dist = tmp_dist
                        self.labels[i] = j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いくつかバグがあるので気づいたものを箇条書きします。

- 特徴空間における距離の計算 (E step) と、どのクラスタに属するかの計算 (M step) は分けて行うべきです。距離の計算を行っている最中にクラスタの割り当てを変えてしまうと、クラスタサイズが計算途中に変わってしまいます。
- クラスタサイズの計算は各イテレーションごとに行う必要があります。
- `data` と `tmp_data`、および `j` と `j+1` を取り違えている箇所があります。E step と M step を分けるとそもそも `tmp_***` を作る必要もインデックスをずらす必要も無くなり、単純になると思います。
- 収束判定が無いので毎回 `max_iter` 回繰り返しています。ただしこれは無くてもクラスタリング結果は変わりません。

また、バグでは無いと思いますが、半径1の円と半径2の円だと分離しにくいみたいです。こちらの環境で自分で書き直した実装と[他の方](https://qiita.com/sz_dr/items/4a7ad994c48a08e86a88)の[実装](https://github.com/szdr/KernelKMeans)でも試してみたのですが、γ=0.1 の RBF では分離できませんでした。半径1と半径5であれば分離できることを確認しました。

Comment: nekketsuuuさんお久しぶりです。回答ありがとうございます。クラスタサイズの計算、抜けていますね、、

「特徴空間における距離の計算 (E step) と、どのクラスタに属するかの計算 (M step) を分けて行うと距離を保存する必要があります」について

あとでargminを使いますよね、そうなると計算量が増えると思ったんですがそんなことないんですか？

artificial dataについてr=1,2では分離しにくいんですか！ありがとうございます。#######とりあえずコードを一部変更します。

Comment: E,Mステップ、それぞれを分けたコードに更新しましたが、クラスの割り当てが全くダメになってしまいました、どこがおかしいでしょうか？

Comment: E step と M step を同時にしてしまうと、計算量以前の問題として、計算結果が変わってしまいます。たとえばカーネル関数が恒等関数、クラスタ数が2だとして、長方形の4頂点+その上に1点追加した5点のデータ [(0,0), (0,2), (3, 2), (3, 0), (2, 3)] を考えます。するとある初期状態から K-means した場合、E と M を分けて行うか同時に行うかで収束結果が変わります。紙の上でも計算できますが、確認のためにプログラムも書いたのでご参照ください: https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/4db3f47ac6841b139c3faf3aa9b3da49

Comment: 質問文のコードが変わっていますが、こうなると私の今の回答が何に対して回答したものかわかりづらくなってしまいます。改変後のコードは追記として別に書いて頂くか、gist 等に貼り付けてこちらにコメントする形にして頂けませんでしょうか？　[編集履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/44792/revisions)から変更前の版にロールバックして、それから追記し直して頂けると簡単です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。gists後ほど確認させていただきます。
変更したコードについて
https://github.com/kiwamizamurai/kiwamizamurai.github.io/tree/master/codes/ipynb

にKMEANS_KERNEL.ipynbとしてアップしました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 更新後のコードについてですが、`distance` 関数において `tmp_data` とすべきところが二箇所 `self.X` になっています。

Comment: tmp_dataに変えなければならないと思われるところを変更後実行しました。linear,sigmoidは全くダメでrbfについても良い結果になりません、データも半径1,5の物を使っているのですが、どうしてでしょう、、、

Comment: とりあえずこちらの環境では、`gamma` を 0.1 にすれば RBF で分類はできました: https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/e956a3a15844c4d149422c03a93290c2

Comment: なるほど！gammaをいじればよかったんですね。本当にありがとうございます。追加で質問なんですがkernel_matrixにおけるpairwise_kernels(X, Y, metric = self.kernel,filter_params = True, **params)なんですが"**params"がどういう感じで使えば良いかを教えてもらえませんか？この部分に関しては　https://gist.github.com/mblondel/6230787 この方のもをの使わせていただきました。

Comment: コメントにするには長いので、別質問として上げて下さいませんか？

Comment: かしこまりました。別の質問として投稿します。